# Componente matDatepicker

Tags: angular

Assim o valor que vem do banco de dados é preenchido no componente

```
<input matInput disabled
name="dataInicio" [(ngModel)]="empresa.dataInicio"
placeholder="Data início de atividade do banco *">
```

Assim não:

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="dataInicio" disabled
name="dataInicio" [(ngModel)]="empresa.dataInicio"
placeholder="Data início de atividade do banco *">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dataInicio"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #dataInicio disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
```

No modelo este campos está assim: **dataInicio: Date;** ou assim **dataInicio: string;**, não é preenchido.

O que pode ser ?